# WHERE NOT IN AND WHERE error

Tags: php, mysqli, codeigniter-3

I tried moving the WHERE clause many times but I'm still having an error. Am I doing the WHERE NOT IN AND WHERE clause wrong? The code is working perfectly fine until I added the **WHERE ha_rooms.deleted != 1** clause. I also tried using deleted <> 1 but it still shows the same error

```
$query2 = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM ha_rooms
    WHERE ha_rooms.deleted != 1 JOIN ha_user_room_merged
    WHERE ha_rooms.room_id NOT IN (SELECT ha_user_room_merged.room_id
    FROM ha_user_room_merged WHERE ha_user_room_merged.deleted = 0)
    group by ha_rooms.room_id");
```

The error is this

---

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'JOIN ha_user_room_merged WHERE ha_rooms.room_id NOT IN (SELECT
>   ha_user_room_merg' at line 1

Comment: `WHERE` *before* `JOIN` is invalid; there may also only be *one* `WHERE` clause per `SELECT`. To see valid syntax, [consult the MySQL Reference Manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select.html). "You can't just make stuff up."

Comment: Your query has many problems.  Please add sample data for both your tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**If I said frankly**, your query is not done properly in anyway but it gives pretty much clear vision of what you are trying to do if you don't have any other logic behind that. So, I would like to suggest you to do google for `SQL Syntax, Ordering, use of GROUP BY, WHERE sub-query etc`. BTW below is the proper version of your query please check if it's useful for you

```
SELECT hr.* 
FROM ha_rooms hr
JOIN ha_user_room_merged hurm On hurm.room_id = hr.room_id
WHERE hurm.deleted = 0 
AND hr.deleted <> 1
```

Comment: The only where clause that is being read by sql here is where hr.deleted<>0. Idk y but it still shows hurm.deleted <>0 But its working

Comment: I found out why my code is not working. Thanks to this.

Answer (score 0):

Please try..

```
select * from ha_rooms as a inner join ha_user_room_merged b on a.ha_rooms.id = b.room_id
where b.deleted <> 0
```

Output

```
ha_rooms.room_id    ha_user_room_merged.room_id   deleted
1                    1                             1
2                    2                             1
3                    3                             1
4                    4                             1
```

Thanks :)

Comment: I need to join the two tables tho. Cant I use SELECT * FROM ha_rooms
   JOIN ha_user_room_merged  WHERE ha_rooms.deleted != 1 AND
    WHERE ha_rooms.room_id NOT IN (SELECT ha_user_room_merged.room_id
    FROM ha_user_room_merged WHERE ha_user_room_merged.deleted = 0)
    group by ha_rooms.room_id

Comment: where do you want to join ha_user_room_merged? on ha_rooms?

Answer (score 0):

Use below codeigniter query. in your join there is no ON

```
$all_ids = 0;
        $this->db->select('group_concat(room_id) as ids');
        $this->db->where('deleted', 0);
        $ids = $this->db->get('ha_user_room_merged')->row_array();
        if($ids) {
            $all_ids = explode(',', $ids['ids']);
        }

        $this->db->where('hr.deleted !=', 1);
        $this->db->where_not_in('hr.room_id', $all_ids);
        $this->db->join('ha_user_room_merged hrm', 'hrm.room_id = hr.room_id');
        $this->db->group_by('hr.room_id');
        $this->db->get('ha_rooms hr')->result_array();
```